# Trying to repair unresolved hyperlinks in TOCs that crop up from time to time in conversions

Tags: calibre, table-of-contents, sigil, hyperlinking

I am converting some of my eBooks to EPUB and using Amazon's Preview app to confirm they're ok to send to them via the email to Kindle collection method.

Commonly my most reoccurring error has to do with unresolvable hyperlinks in the TOC.  I'm not an eBook author and not too proficient with the format, but is there an easy way to fix these occurrences?  How would one go about troubleshooting them, is there a Calibre plug-in or can Sigil do it somehow?  Thanks -

```
Type    Description
Error   E24010: Hyperlink not resolved in toc (One possible reason can be that the link points to a tag with style display:none):C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Temp\b6495039-859f-4bf2-92d1-15eeb2641a7b\cTemp\mTemp\mbp_7E6_5_1A_10_1C_24_123_1B64_25F0_1\text\part0000.html#0-32aaa7c1c1bc45618916fe190f84d7d3
Error   E24001: The table of content could not be built.
Status  Book conversion failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I learned about Calibre's ability to edit and attempt to repair these types of issues.  Bring it into Calibre's book editor w/ 'T' and do a repair check and allow it to repair what it can.  This took care of 98% of the issues I was seeing.